# Java View Html Code as web-page

Tags: java, html

I have a HTML code and I want to view in jeditorpane as web page but I could not it.

html code : http://pastebin.com/S0TEGrH5

**my attempt:**

```
jEditorPane2.setContentType("text/html");

jEditorPane2.setText(htmlcode);
```

After this process  I have only sound like that dıtt and screen is empty.If I save this code as file (file.html) and jeditorpane2.setpage("file.html") Process have succeed .But I don't want to create file Please give an advise to view html code as web page only use code , no creating file )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem  is related to charset.

before the setText you should added this code :

```
jEditorPane2.getDocument().putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

from: http://mrbool.com/display-html-contents-with-java/24532

```
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HtmlContent extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new HtmlContent().start();
    }

    void start() {
        try {
            String html;
            html = "<html><head><title>Simple Page</title></head>";
            html += "<body bgcolor='#777779'><hr/><font size=50>This is Html cont    ent</font><hr/>";
            html += "</body></html>";
            JEditorPane ed1 = new JEditorPane("text/html", html);
            add(ed1);
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(600, 600);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Some problem has occured" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Melit, I thought what you did is that you saved your html in the file but dont want to save it. @dooart isnt saving anything to any file, isn't this exactly what you want?